# how to exclude the debug sample from the summary report in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, load-testing

How to exclude the debug sample from the summary report?

I tried removing but for some reason it does not work the process below, so is there a way to exclude from the results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) just used to print variables for debugging

> Debug PostProcessor creates a subSample with the details of the previous Sampler properties, JMeter variables, properties and/or System Properties.

- You can print variable(s) using JSR223 Pre/Post Processor using

`log.info(vars.get("varName"));
  log.info(props.get("propName"));`

- If you need debugging only in specific GUI testing you can also add Debug Sampler under If Condition which will not work unless you manually set it to true.

Comment: thank you very much ! , I just disabled them and it seems it is working without issues

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Filter Results Tool](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FilterResultsTool/#Filter-Results-Tool) JMeter Plugin like:

```
FilterResults.bat --input-file your_existing_file.jtl --output-file result_without_debug_samplers.jtl --exclude-labels "Debug Sampler"
```

The above command line will parse existing results file and remove any `Debug Sampler` instances from it.

Filter Results Tool plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image: JMeter Plugins Filter results tool]

Upon installation you will find `FilterResults.bat` and `FilterResults.sh` scripts under JMeter's "bin" folder